# PHP mysqli adding multipe entries for one insert

Tags: php, database, mysql

the following short PHP code should be adding 1 entry into the database table. however when I run this I find 3 identical entries.
MySQL Server version: 5.5.39 - MySQL Community Server

PHP/5.4.31

```
<?PHP
// connect to temp DB
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "tempdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($conn->connect_error)
   {  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);  }
$mysqlstr = "    INSERT INTO 
    tempproduct (
        `productName`, `MerchantID`,  `Merchant`, `myLink`, `Thumbnail`, 
        `BigImage`, `Price`, `RetailPrice`, `Category`, `Subcategory`, 
        `Description`, 
        `Custom1`, `Custom2`, `Custom3`, `Custom4`,  `Custom5`, 
        `Lastupdated`, `productStatus`, `Manufacturer`, 
        `PartNumber`, `MerchantCategory`, `MerchantSubcategory`, 
        `ShortDescription`, 
        `ISBN`, `UPC`, `SKU`, `CrossSell`, 
        `MerchantGroup`, `MerchantSubgroup`, `CompatibleWith`, 
        `CompareTo`, `QuantityDiscount`, `Bestseller`, `AddToCartURL`, 
        `ReviewsRSSURL`, `Option1`, `Option2`, `Option3`, `Option4`, 
        `Option5`, `MobileURL`, `MobileImage`, `MobileThumbnail`
    ) 
    VALUES(
         'Fossil Editor Leather Ladies Watch ES3242', '32800', 'Pricefalls.com',  '[some url]', '[some url]', 
         '[some url]', '113.10', '145', 'Fashion', 'Jewelry', 
         'Stainless steel case. White leather strap. White dial. Day date and 24-hour time. Quartz movement. Water resistant 50 meters. Case 38mm. Buckle closure.', 
         'Silver', 'Stainless Steel', '', '38', 'female', 
         '2015-06-24 14:21:30',  'instock', 'Fossil', 
         'ES3242', 'Jewelry & Watches', 'Watches', 
         'Stainless steel case. White leather strap. White dial. Day date and 24-hour time. Quartz movement. Water resistant 50 meters. Case 38mm. Buckle closure.', 
         '', '691464976040', '4907551', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
         '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''
    )";
mysqli_query($conn,$mysqlstr);
// $conn->query($mysqlstr);
  echo "done";
 $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the script only once?

Comment: Make sure your webserver isn't sending 404s for things like `favicon.ico` that the browser requests automatically to your PHP script.

Comment: Do some basic debugging: log script execution.

Comment: i have killed the script just prior to mysqli_query($conn,$mysqlstr); and there are no entries in the database. nothing else is running on the server. and I have rebooted prior to running the script once.  BTW this is a windows machine running xampp  1.8.2

Comment: pasting the myqlstr into phpmyadmin it works fine

Comment: There's nothing in that bit of code that would cause multiple inserts. It could be; including the file multiple times, or refreshing the page, or something else.

Comment: So, what happened then you wrote a little log file from your script?

Comment: alvaro how would you recommend logging this script.

dan08 - the script is exactly as here other than the some URL no includes nor is it included. also no refresh. so must be the something else. trying to find the something else.

Comment: I found the problem is the database itself. Created a new database. exported the table from the old database, imported into new one and works fine there. old database still does 3 entries every time. even in a new table.  Curious as to what would cause this but that would probably be a new question.